# How to implement source code on azure website, from a storage blob with C #?

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

How to copy files programmatically from an azure storage blob to an in azure website?
The goal is to create a custom and manageable deployment.

With the new azure-sdk-for-net I can only deploy a site with public git.

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand your question. Can you please edit and clarify what you're trying to solve?

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dropbox/One drive for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-deploy-content-sync

Comment: I intend to do this programmatically, it's a necessity of mine.
Because I will have several clients that need to be updated and not necessarily all at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

> How to copy files programmatically from an azure storage blob to an in azure website? The goal is to create a custom and manageable deployment.

It seems that you’d like to upload/push files to Azure Web Site folder programmatically, as we know, Azure Web Site enables us to access its files via FTP,  you could try to add some FTP client libraries in your project and upload files to Azure Web Site FTP server in your program. Besides, the [Zip API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) allows expanding zip files into folder of Azure Web Site, you could pull files from Azure Blob storage in memory or local storage, and then upload and expand zip files into Azure Web Site folder by calling this API in your program.

*Request of expanding zip files into folder of Azure Web Site*

[image]

Note: accessing/downloading files from Azure storage will be charged.

Comment: I asked in the hope that something is already ready, but this is a totally viable alternative. Thank you for your feedback.